# Does SQLCMD "!!" command work in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sqlcmd, azure-data-studio

In SQL Server Management Studio, it is possible to run batch commands when in [SQLCMD mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor), using the [!! command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility#:%7E:text=%5B:%5D%20!!%3C%20command%3E). However, in Azure Data Studio, this does not seem to work (SQLCMD has been available in ADS since [version 1.13.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/release-notes-azure-data-studio#:%7E:text=SQLCMD%20mode) in November 2019), I'm running ADS as Windows Administrator.

**How can I execute batch commands in Azure Data Studio using SQLCMD mode?**
Did I miss something, or is there some of the (scarce) documentation I need to read?

**- In SQL Server Management Studio:**

[image: Works in SQL Server Management Studio]

**- In Azure Data Studio**

[image: Doesn't work in ADS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [open issue with SQLCMD in ADS](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/7381), where SQLCMD mode fails to parse some sqlcmd keywords. The issue is currently on the backlog.

ADS includes a terminal window (View-->Terminal) so  you can easily run OS commands on your client under the same query tab without SQLCMD.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I wanted some batch commands to be included in the script to get the current folder for `:R` include files. At least now I can check up on the backlog progress/status.